# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at <VM>:7:9 at (<VM boundary>), HookDeck

Tags: json, webhooks

I tried to use HookDeck as my webhook for trying WhatsApp Cloud Api.
There is an error in my code for my webhook using HookDeck, for some reason it can't read the content of my nested jason.

Here some screenshot :
[image]

From the image (left) there should be a value field inside changes, but some reason won't get detected when I ran the code.

I'm a newbie about webhook and this is for learning WhatsApp Cloud API and want to create webhook on my own without using webhook provided by the documentation.
Thanks*emphasized text*

Comment: `body.entry` is an Array. Therefore, `c = a.changes` results in `a` having a value of `undefined`. Thus, `c.value` will throw an error. The code above would have to be updated to `a = body.entry[0]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think HookDeck can do things I want to do and there is not enough information/documentation about this. I'll reconsider using another or create my own webhook.